# Google Transliteration API dosent work on dynamic textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Google Transliteration API doesn't working on dynamic newly created forms.
In the code Google Transliteration API work on all the input items that has a id `enbn` but when we dynamically create a new textarea with the id `enbn` javascript seems not to be listening for the event. 
How the transliteration api will work for newly created textarea's? 
Example: http://codepen.io/rakib/pen/EjmyxN

Comment: `id`s must be unique, so only one per document, if you are repeating the `endn` id it will cause issues

Comment: using unique id doesn't seems to work

Comment: console is throwing `Uncaught Error: Exception in showControl: No div exists with id translControl`, the code is targeting element that are not present.

Comment: ok, that was another issue i think was not related to this problem